# Command: mysql --print-defaults not recognized?

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, zend-server-ce

I am trying to set some defaults in my.cnf and when I tried to check MySQL's current defaults I got an error!

- Using Zend Server CE 5.5
- *on* OSX 10.6.8

And here is the command and subsequent error:

```
$ mysql --print-defaults
/usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysql.client: unknown option '--print-defaults'
```

When I type `--help` it shows the `--print-defaults` as an option.

---

#### Am I doing something wrong? Has anyone else experienced this?

(**Note**: if this question belongs on Super User please let me know and don't downvote it -- unless it actually deserves one.)

---

Edit

I tried doing `mysqld --print-defaults` and as I reported it didn't work either. So I checked if it was running and this is what I got:

```
$ ps aux | grep mysqld
 5:36PM  0:00.01 grep mysqld
Mon02AM  2:24.61 /usr/local/zend/mysql/bin/mysqld 
                 --defaults-extra-file=/usr/local/zend/mysql/data/my.cnf 
                 --basedir=/usr/local/zend/mysql 
                 --datadir=/usr/local/zend/mysql/data 
                 --user=zend 
                 --log-error=/usr/local/zend/mysql/data/mycomputer.local.err 
                 --pid-file=/usr/local/zend/mysql/data/mycomputer.local.pid 
                 --socket=/usr/local/zend/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock --port=3306
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql` is the client program.

What you want is the server. Run this please

```
mysqld --print-defaults
```

I found it by asking the server

```
mysqld --help --verbose | grep print
```

and I got this

```
--print-defaults        Print the program argument list and exit.
```

A safer method is to use mysqladmin

```
mysqladmin -uuser -ppassword variables
```

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: I tried the first one and got this: `$ mysqld --print-defaults (new-line)
mysqld would have been started with the following arguments:
` and an empty argument list

Comment: Make sure mysqld is running when you call `mysqld --print-defaults`

Comment: check my edit, mysqld is running and it still doesn't work.. Any ideas?

Comment: Many years later...You were right though it never worked for Zend Server because Zend Server sucks and especially back then. I had stopped using it years ago and just recently ran across this old Q.  **Solution:** _never_ use zend server.  `brew install httpd` ftw.  Even MAMP is better.  Code tracing was the only worthwhile feature of ZS and it was buggy anyway.